# Changing Geb baseUrl in runtime

Tags: selenium, spock, geb

I want to write and end to end test that involves 2 systems

- System 1: `www.sys1.com`
- System 2: `www.sys2.com`

The process that im trying to test starts with system 1 and eventually I will be able to see changes in system 2. When I start my tests, I pass the following parameter to geb

```
-Dgeb.build.baseUrl=http://www.sys1.com/
```

I want somehow in the middle of my test to reconfigure the baseUrl so i can navigate to pages in `www.sys2.com`

Is this possible? if so how?

Tech stuff:

- Geb 1.1.1
- Selenium 3.0.1
- Groovy 2.4.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using browser.setBaseUrl:

APage:

```
class APage extends Page
{
   static url = "myUrl/"
}
```

Geb Config:

```
baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/"
```

Example:

```
    browser.to(APage) //Goes to http://www.google.com/myUrl/

    browser.setBaseUrl("http://www.mynewurl.com/") // sets new baseUrl

    browser.to(APage) //Goes to http://www.mynewurl.com/myUrl/
```